# phpstorm unsaved files color

Tags: phpstorm

How do I see if a file has changed on PHPstorm?

I need to sync the files on ftp and that happens when I save (ctrl+s), but if I have many files I can't keep track of them, how do I see if there are changes.

I have tried with the color, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` |`Editor Tabs` | **Mark Modified tabs with asterisk**

[image]

Comment: maybe I am blind, but in PHPStorm 7 on OSX, this feature not seem to work :/
Anyone have a solution about this?

Comment: sorry, it works. It's just really invisible with it's stupid dark blue :)

Comment: try a search on setting by "modified tabs"

Comment: to JetBrains: This **should be set as default**

Comment: It is not set by default because the - Save files on frame deactivation - is activarted by default

Answer (score 3):

in OSX, On the top toolbar, go to PHPStorm > Preferences... > Editor > Editor Tabs, and then select the box for `Mark modified tabs with asterisk`.
 (then hit `OK` at the bottom)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the asterisk next to the name as the accepted answer gives you. During my odyssey to find that answer I also found another useful way to display changed files, in the project view click on the down arrow next to the project name and select "Changed Files".

Answer (score 2):

**PhpStorm 2019.2**

Now is in `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Editor Tabs` | `Appearance` | **Mark modified (*)**

[image: screenshotPhpStoem2019Settings]

[More](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206931095-How-can-I-see-if-a-file-has-been-saved?page=1#community_comment_360000681020)